# Global Temporary Table with "On commit delete rows" is not holding any data

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, temp-tables

I have a global temporary table (GTT) defined in a creation script using the option to delete rows on commit. I wanted to be able to have different users see their own data in the GTT and not the data of other people's sessions. This worked perfectly in our test environment.

But then, I deployed GTT as part of an update to functionality to a client's database. The client called me up all upset and worried, because the GTT wasn't holding any data any more, and they didn't know why.

Specifically, if someone did:

```
insert into my_GTT (description) values ('Happy happy joy joy')
```

the database would respond:

```
1 row inserted.
```

However, if the same end user tried:

```
select * from my_GTT
```

The database would respond:

```
0 rows returned.
```

This issue is happening on the client site, and we can't reproduce it in house. What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: What is "playmate" - is that another session? Have you tried changing the table to ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS, just to see what happens?

Comment: "Playmate" is an end user. This issue is happening on the client site, and we can't reproduce it in house. Also, I don't have any control over changing the table code, since it's on the client site.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? On the face of it, a permissions issue (i.e. user allowed to write but not to read) seems less likely than an autocommit setting somewhere.

Comment: Looking back at this question now, my attempt to make it funny leaves me wondering "what the heck was this question about?", I don't even recall what system I had this issue in (now my old job)

Answer (score 3):

`ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` = data in one transaction

`ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` = data in one database session (one user with 2 sessions = 2 session = different content)

If GTT is defined with `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS`, it would be empty after any explicit commit or implicit commit (= implicit commit = after any DLL command including for example truncate table, alter index, add partition, modify column, exchange partition):

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE GTT__TEST (A NUMBER) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
INSERT INTO GTT__TEST VALUES (1); 
SELECT * FROM GTT__TEST; -- 1 ROW; 
COMMIT; -- commit = delete rows
SELECT * FROM GTT__TEST; -- 0 ROWS; 
INSERT INTO GTT__TEST VALUES (1); 
SELECT * FROM GTT__TEST; -- 1 ROW; 
ALTER TABLE GTT__TEST MODIFY A NOT NULL; -- DLL = commit = delete rows
SELECT * FROM GTT__TEST; -- 0 ROWS
```

If GTT is defined with `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`, it would hold data till end of session:

```
DROP TABLE GTT__TEST; 
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE GTT__TEST (A NUMBER) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
INSERT INTO GTT__TEST VALUES (1); 
SELECT * FROM GTT__TEST; -- 1 ROW 
COMMIT; 
SELECT * FROM GTT__TEST; -- 1 ROW
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have some setting turned on in your target environment where each statement is auto-committing?

(My experience is in SQL Server, where such is the default, but I understand in Oracle, the default is to keep the transaction open until an explicit commit. Mind, I haven't touched Oracle since ~2000)

Comment: As far as I know, it is not set to autocommit. We have to code to explicitly commit things, and strings of procedures inserting things into other tables undo themselves if we raise exceptions in code.

Answer (score 0):

I think Damien is right and there is an autocommit. The only other option I can come up with is some sort of connection pool issue (ie the select is being done from a separate session to the insert)

Comment: The session is the same for the select and the insert. This issue has been with the DBAs since I posted the original question, and I'm not sure of the progress, apart from the fact it may be related to read/update permissions for the user.